# How to populate the flex table in GWT from the backend

Tags: gwt, database-connection, uibinder, flextable

I have to pull out values from backend and fill it as rows in the flex table. I am not using static data, so I cannot use:

```
table.setText(0, 0, "Name");
table.setText(0, 1,"Birthdate");
table.setText(0, 2, "Address");
```

How can I pull out data and fill it as rows in flex table. Or should I use a Grid table for the same?

Comment: Have you looked at CellTable, this may help if you have a known collection of entities. It is much faster and more flexible for things like paging sorting etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's about something like this. In another class you could load your data from backend and create new Car Objekts and pass them to the MyCarFlexTable class.

```
class MyCarFlexTable extends FlexTable {

 private int rowNumber;
 private List<Car> cars;

 public MyCarFlexTable(List<Car> cars) {
  this.cars = cars;
  initTable();
 }

 private void initTable() {
  for(Car c : cars) {
   // define which data is printed in which column
   setText(rowNumber, 0, c.getId()); // Id of Car
   setWidget(rowNumber, 1, new Label(c.getName())); // Name of Car
   // add more Columns
   rowNumber++;
  }
 }
}
```